# Hide Account from Wordpress Users List based on role

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide all the accounts having 'Administrator' role assigned or by certain ID from Wordpress Users list. I've tried this code so far but doesn't work as expected:

```
add_action('pre_user_query','rudr_completely_hide_user');

function rudr_completely_hide_user( $u_query ) {

    // let's allow the hidden user to see himself
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($current_user->ID != 2) { // the user with ID = 2 for example
        global $wpdb;
        // just str_replace() the SQL query 
        $u_query->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1', "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID<>2", $u_query->query_where); // do not forget to change user ID here as well
    }

}
```